# How to give border bottom to heading with font awesome icon

Tags: html, css

In my first div container, I added a heading 1 tag, gave a border bottom a color of my desire, and added font awesome icon in the middle.

As you can see I had to give a background color on the font awesome to make it appear transparent. but now I have a background image on the second box so I am struggling to achieve the same thing.

How can I do the same on my other div box without affecting the background image 
 visibility as well as the border bottom from the heading 1?

```css
div.container{
  background-image: url(http://az616578.vo.msecnd.net/files/2016/04/09/6359580807140768861266757027_Never-Study-Hard-The-Art-of-Studying-Smart.jpg);
  
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
}
div{
  height: 100px;
}
h1.widget_title_1{
    font-size: 25pt;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 35px;
    padding-bottom: 9px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #898989;
    position: relative;
}
h1.widget_title_1:after {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: fontawesome;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 58px;
    margin-top: -7px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    font-size: 24pt;
    color: black;
    content: '\f107';
    font-weight: 300;
    background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div class="container-1">
  <h1 class="widget_title_1">
    heading 1
  </h1>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="widget_title">
    heading 1
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/line-on-sides-headers/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you to use `font-awesome icons` along-with `tag` as here I have used `i tag`, it get's easy to `align icon` i.e. at `center` of that div tag, just by using `text-align:center`. Then you can use pseudo selector `:before` and `:after` on `h1` tag and add that `border`. Scale `to and fro` on this [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ddc0vLth/) and see `border` doesn't get's `attached` at certain screen resolution.

```css
.container-1 {
  height: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container-1 > .widget_title_1 {
  font-size: 25pt;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.container-1 > .fa {
  font-size: 24px;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container-1 > .widget_title_1:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #111;
  bottom: -38%;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.container-1 > .widget_title_1:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #111;
  bottom: -38%;
  margin-right: -10px;
  right: 0;
}

.container {
  background-image: url(http://az616578.vo.msecnd.net/files/2016/04/09/6359580807140768861266757027_Never-Study-Hard-The-Art-of-Studying-Smart.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.container > .widget_title {
  font-size: 25pt;
  margin: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}

.container > .fa {
  font-size: 24px;
  display: block;
  height: 30px;
  width: 138px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container > .widget_title:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #111;
  bottom: -38%;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: -10px;
}

.container > .widget_title:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 2px;
  background: #111;
  bottom: -38%;
  margin-right: -10px;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
<div class="container-1">
  <h1 class="widget_title_1">
    heading 1
  </h1>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="widget_title">
    heading 1
  </h1>
  <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `:before` `:after` for div for the line.
Create a span tag with the font awesome as shown below.

```css
    div.container{
      background-image: url(http://az616578.vo.msecnd.net/files/2016/04/09/6359580807140768861266757027_Never-Study-Hard-The-Art-of-Studying-Smart.jpg);
      
      background-size: cover;
      background-position: 50%;
    }
    div{
      position: relative;
      height: 100px;
    }
    h1.widget_title_1{
        font-size: 25pt;
        display: inline-block;
        margin: 0;
        margin-top: 35px;
        padding-bottom: 9px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #898989;
        position: relative;
    }
    span:after {
        position: absolute;
        font-family: fontawesome;
        display: block;
        margin-left: 58px;
        margin-top: -7px;
        top:40px;
        padding: 0 5px;
        font-size: 24pt;
        color: black;
        content: '\f107';
        font-weight: 300;
        background-color: transparent;
    }
    div.container:after{
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        height: 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        top: 45px;
        width: 60px;
    }
    div.container:before{
        content: "";
        position: absolute;
        height: 5px;
        border-bottom: 1px solid black;
        top: 45px;
        left:90px;
        width: 60px;
    }
```

```html
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <div class="container-1">
      <h1 class="widget_title_1">
        heading 1
      </h1>

    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <h1 class="widget_title">
        heading 1
      </h1>
      <span></span>
    </div>
```

Comment: I just tried this and is giving me a few problems with responsiveness. I tried to put the h1 in the center. hope you don't mind editing your.
Am testing the changes in this snippet:
http://codepen.io/Sidney-Dev/pen/pPxZVy

Comment: I just gave a proof of code.Most of the things are hardcoded, you need to change the css properties from pixel to percentage according to the need.Then it will be responsive.